# android parsing Feed RSS images

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm using this library https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library to parse Feed RSS. I tried to edit it for get also the images but i don't know if I am in the right way and I don't know how to edit RssHandler.java
The images I want to parse are enclosed in an img Tag.

Thanks for the help!

Here the code:

RssFeed.java

```
public class RssFeed implements Parcelable {

private String title;
private String link;
private String description;
private String language;
private String imageUrl;
private ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems;

public RssFeed() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public RssFeed(Parcel source) {

    Bundle data = source.readBundle();
    title = data.getString("title");
    link = data.getString("link");
    description = data.getString("description");
    language = data.getString("language");
    imageUrl = data.getString("imageUrl");
    rssItems = data.getParcelableArrayList("rssItems");

}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("title", title);
    data.putString("link", link);
    data.putString("description", description);
    data.putString("language", language);
    data.putString("imageUrl", imageUrl);
    data.putParcelableArrayList("rssItems", rssItems);
    dest.writeBundle(data);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<RssFeed> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RssFeed>() {
    public RssFeed createFromParcel(Parcel data) {
        return new RssFeed(data);
    }
    public RssFeed[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RssFeed[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

void addRssItem(RssItem rssItem) {
    rssItems.add(rssItem);
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public ArrayList<RssItem> getRssItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

public void setRssItems(ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems) {
    this.rssItems = rssItems;
} 
}
```

RssItem.java

```
public class RssItem implements Comparable<RssItem>, Parcelable {

private RssFeed feed;
private String title;
private String link;
private Date pubDate;
private String description;
private String content;
private String imageUrl;

public RssItem() {

}

public RssItem(Parcel source) {

    Bundle data = source.readBundle();
    title = data.getString("title");
    link = data.getString("link");
    pubDate = (Date) data.getSerializable("pubDate");
    description = data.getString("description");
    content = data.getString("content");
    imageUrl = data.getString("imageUrl");
    feed = data.getParcelable("feed");

}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("title", title);
    data.putString("link", link);
    data.putSerializable("pubDate", pubDate);
    data.putString("description", description);
    data.putString("content", content);
    data.putString("imageUrl", imageUrl);
    data.putParcelable("feed", feed);
    dest.writeBundle(data);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<RssItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RssItem>() {
    public RssItem createFromParcel(Parcel data) {
        return new RssItem(data);
    }
    public RssItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RssItem[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public RssFeed getFeed() {
    return feed;
}

public void setFeed(RssFeed feed) {
    this.feed = feed;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public Date getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(Date pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        this.pubDate = dateFormat.parse(pubDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(RssItem another) {
    if(getPubDate() != null && another.getPubDate() != null) {
        return getPubDate().compareTo(another.getPubDate());
    } else { 
        return 0;
    }
}

}
```

RssReader.java

```
public class RssReader {

public static RssFeed read(URL url) throws SAXException, IOException {

    return read(url.openStream());

}

public static RssFeed read(InputStream stream) throws SAXException, IOException {

    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();
        InputSource input = new InputSource(stream);

        reader.setContentHandler(handler);
        reader.parse(input);

        return handler.getResult();

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new SAXException();
    }

}

}
```

RssHandler.java

```
public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private RssFeed rssFeed;
private RssItem rssItem;
private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

@Override
public void startDocument() {
    rssFeed = new RssFeed();
}

/**
 * Return the parsed RssFeed with it's RssItems
 * @return
 */
public RssFeed getResult() {
    return rssFeed;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if(qName.equals("item") && rssFeed != null) {
        rssItem = new RssItem();
        rssItem.setFeed(rssFeed);
        rssFeed.addRssItem(rssItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    stringBuilder.append(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {

    if(rssFeed != null && rssItem == null) {
        // Parse feed properties

        try {
            if (qName != null && qName.length() > 0) {
                String methodName = "set" + qName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + qName.substring(1);
                Method method = rssFeed.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
                method.invoke(rssFeed, stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }

    } else if (rssItem != null) {
        // Parse item properties

        try {
            if(qName.equals("content:encoded")) 
                qName = "content";
            String methodName = "set" + qName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + qName.substring(1);
            Method method = rssItem.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
            method.invoke(rssItem, stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get images from  tags either via an XML parser or via complex regex.

Try using this library for RSS:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It's easy to use and works with most feeds by default. You can also plug in your own parser for custom content. The parser Java files in this library have an example of what I mean by using Android's XmlPullParser to get the image tag content.